# Notifier Provider keeps changing value

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am using notifier providers to pass some values from page to page. It works well but I am having a problem with one variable changing value when I tap on a listview tile.

In the class, I have a copyWith method that I use to change the different variables in the class.

Here is the Notifier class:

```
class Globals {
  final String? currentUid;
  final String? currentUEmail;
  final String? userDocumentId;
  final String? companyId;
  final String? mlsId;
  final String? currentTrxnId;
  final String? currentCompanyName;
  final String? currentCompanyState;
  final String? currentUserId;
  final String? currentUserState;
  final String? currentUserName;
  final String? selectedState;
  final String? selectedUserState;
  final String? selectedTrxnState;
  final String? selectedCompany;
  final String? selectedUser;
  final String? userBusinessType;
  final int? targetScreen;
  final bool? newEvent;
  final bool? newTrxn;
  final bool? newUser;
  final bool newCompany;
  final bool? addCompany;

  Globals({
    this.currentUid,
    this.currentUEmail,
    this.userDocumentId,
    this.companyId,
    this.mlsId,
    this.currentTrxnId,
    this.currentCompanyName,
    this.currentCompanyState,
    this.currentUserId,
    this.currentUserState,
    this.currentUserName,
    this.selectedState,
    this.selectedUserState,
    this.selectedTrxnState,
    this.selectedCompany,
    this.selectedUser,
    this.userBusinessType,
    this.targetScreen,
    this.newEvent,
    this.newTrxn,
    this.newUser,
    this.addCompany,
    required this.newCompany,
  });

  Globals copyWith({
    String? currentUid,
    String? currentUEmail,
    String? userDocumentId,
    String? companyId,
    String? mlsId,
    String? currentTrxnId,
    String? currentCompanyName,
    String? currentCompanyState,
    String? currentUserId,
    String? currentUserState,
    String? currentUserName,
    String? selectedState,
    String? selectedUserState,
    String? selectedTrxnState,
    String? selectedCompany,
    String? selectedUser,
    String? userBusinessType,
    int? targetScreen,
    bool newEvent = true,  <<< PROBLEM HERE
    bool newTrxn = true,  <<< PROBLEM HERE
    bool newUser = true,  <<< PROBLEM HERE
    bool newCompany = true,  <<< PROBLEM HERE
    bool addCompany = false,  <<< PROBLEM HERE
  }) {
    return Globals(
      currentUid: currentUid ?? this.currentUid,
      currentUEmail: currentUEmail ?? this.currentUEmail,
      userDocumentId: userDocumentId ?? this.userDocumentId,
      companyId: companyId ?? this.companyId,
      mlsId: mlsId ?? this.mlsId,
      currentTrxnId: currentTrxnId ?? this.currentTrxnId,
      currentCompanyName: currentCompanyName ?? this.currentCompanyName,
      currentCompanyState: currentCompanyState ?? this.currentCompanyState,
      currentUserId: currentUserId ?? this.currentUserId,
      currentUserState: currentUserState ?? this.currentUserState,
      currentUserName: currentUserName ?? this.currentUserName,
      selectedState: selectedState ?? this.selectedState,
      selectedUserState: selectedUserState ?? this.selectedUserState,
      selectedTrxnState: selectedTrxnState ?? this.selectedTrxnState,
      selectedCompany: selectedCompany ?? this.selectedCompany,
      selectedUser: selectedUser ?? this.selectedUser,
      userBusinessType: userBusinessType ?? this.userBusinessType,
      targetScreen: targetScreen ?? this.targetScreen,
      newEvent: newEvent,
      newTrxn: newTrxn,
      newUser: newUser,
      newCompany: newCompany,
      addCompany: addCompany,
    );
  }
}

class GlobalsNotifier extends Notifier<Globals> {
  @override
  Globals build() {
    return Globals(
      currentUid: '',
      currentUEmail: '',
      userDocumentId: '',
      companyId: '',
      mlsId: '',
      currentTrxnId: '',
      currentCompanyName: '',
      currentCompanyState: '',
      currentUserId: '',
      currentUserName: '',
      currentUserState: '',
      selectedCompany: '',
      selectedState: '',
      selectedTrxnState: '',
      selectedUser: '',
      selectedUserState: '',
      userBusinessType: '',
      targetScreen: 0,
      newCompany: true,
      newEvent: true,
      newTrxn: true,
      newUser: true,
      addCompany: false,
    );
  }

  // functions to update class members
  void updatecurrentUid(String newcurrentUid) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentUid: newcurrentUid);
  }

  void updatecurrentUEmail(String? newcurrentUEmail) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentUEmail: newcurrentUEmail);
  }

  void updateuserDocumentId(String newuserDocumentId) {
    state = state.copyWith(userDocumentId: newuserDocumentId);
  }

  void updatecompanyId(String newcompanyId) {
    state = state.copyWith(companyId: newcompanyId);
  }

  void updatemlsId(String newmlsId) {
    state = state.copyWith(mlsId: newmlsId);
  }

  void updatecurrentTrxnId(String? newcurrentTrxnId) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentTrxnId: newcurrentTrxnId);
  }

  void updatecurrentCompanyName(String newcurrentCompanyName) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentCompanyName: newcurrentCompanyName);
  }

  void updatecurrentCompanyState(String newcurrentCompanyState) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentCompanyState: newcurrentCompanyState);
  }

  void updatecurrentUserId(String newcurrentUserId) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentUserId: newcurrentUserId);
  }

  void updatecurrentUserState(String newcurrentUserState) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentUserState: newcurrentUserState);
  }

  void updatecurrentUserName(String newcurrentUserName) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentUserName: newcurrentUserName);
  }

  void updateselectedState(String newselectedState) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedState: newselectedState);
  }

  void updateselectedUserState(String newselectedUserState) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedUserState: newselectedUserState);
  }

  void updateselectedTrxnState(String newselectedTrxnState) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedTrxnState: newselectedTrxnState);
  }

  void updateselectedCompany(String newselectedCompany) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedCompany: newselectedCompany);
  }

  void updateselectedUser(String newselectedUser) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedUser: newselectedUser);
  }

  void updateUserBusinessType(String newUserBusinessType) {
    state = state.copyWith(userBusinessType: newUserBusinessType);
  }

  void updatetargetScreen(int newtargetScreen) {
    state = state.copyWith(targetScreen: newtargetScreen);
  }

  void updatenewEvent(bool newNewEvent) {
    state = state.copyWith(newEvent: newNewEvent);
  }

  void updatenewTrxn(bool newNewTrxn) {
    state = state.copyWith(newTrxn: newNewTrxn);
  }

  void updatenewUser(bool newNewUser) {
    state = state.copyWith(newUser: newNewUser);
  }

  void updatenewCompany(bool newNewCompany) {
    state = state.copyWith(newCompany: newNewCompany);
  }

  void updateAddCompany(bool newAddCompany) {
    state = state.copyWith(addCompany: newAddCompany);
  }
}

final globalsNotifierProvider = NotifierProvider<GlobalsNotifier, Globals>(() {
  return GlobalsNotifier();
});
```

I discovered the problem when I was trying to edit a transaction record in the db. To distinguish a new record from an existing one, I set newTrxn to true for a new record and false for an existing record.

In the listview tile onTap event, I set newTrxn = false because it is an existing record in the db.

I hope this all makes sense so far.

Here is the class code for the customer dashboard where I have the listview:

```
final FirestoreService firestoreService = FirestoreService();

class CompanyDashboardScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'user_dashboard_screen';

  const CompanyDashboardScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<CompanyDashboardScreen> createState() =>
      _CompanyDashboardScreenState();
}

class _CompanyDashboardScreenState
    extends ConsumerState<CompanyDashboardScreen> {
  bool showSpinner = false;

  bool isLoaded = false;

  setGlobals(String? Id) {
    ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewTrxn(false);
    ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatecurrentTrxnId(Id);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: CustomAppBar(),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: const Text("User Profile"),
                onTap: () {
                  MainScreen.of(context)
                      ?.setIndex(3); // Added this for BottomNavigationBar sync
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const UserProfileScreen()));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot?>(
              future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('company')
                  .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId)
                  .collection('trxns')
                  .get(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return snapshot.hasData
                    ? ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data?.size,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: ListTile(
                              isThreeLine: true,
                              title: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    'Client: ${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['clientFName'] ?? 'n/a'} ${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['clientLName'] ?? 'n/a'}',
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                        color: Colors.blueAccent),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text.rich(
                                TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                      '${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['propertyAddress'] ?? 'n/a'}, '
                                      '${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['propertyCity'] ?? 'n/a'}, '
                                      '${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['propertyState'] ?? 'n/a'}',
                                  children: <TextSpan>[
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text:
                                          '\nPrice: ${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['contractPrice'] == null ? 'n/a' : snapshot.data?.docs[index]['contractPrice']}\nStatus: ${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['trxnStatus'] ?? 'n/a'}',
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                          color: Colors.blueGrey),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              trailing: Text(
                                  'MLS#: ${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['mlsNumber'] ?? 'n/a'}\n${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['clientType']}'),
                              onTap: () {
                                //MainScreen.of(context)?.setIndex(2);  // Added this for BottomNavigationBar sync
                                setGlobals(snapshot.data?.docs[index].id);
                                Navigator.of(context).push(
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        const TransactionDetailScreen(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      )
                    : const Text('No Date');
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the onTap event, I call a method, setGlobals(), that sets a couple of NotifierProvider variables to the desired values. In particular, newTrxn is set to "false" so I can use it in the next screen to populate the textfields.

However, I think because I am changing this value in the onTap event which is inside the build: method, the value gets changed back to "true" which is set in the constructor of the copyWith method of the Notifier class.

How do I stop the value of newTrxn from being changed back from "false" to "true"?